# Why did Jimmy Carter appoint Paul Volcker as Fed Chair?

Tags: united-states, federal-reserve, jimmy-carter

I associate tight money with Thatcher, and after Thatcher, Reagan (who I also associate with Thatcher). Therefore, it came as a surprise to learn that it was Jimmy Carter who appointed Volcker - who I also associate with tight money - as Fed Chair.

I understand that Jimmy Carter had to appoint somebody in a hurry, since his emergency inflation reshuffle - that I've learnt from my research - but why the choice of Volcker?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Political vs. technocratic appointments**
Usually such appointments are not political, but rather based on competences. It is like career diplomates in the state department - one does not withdraw/fire all the officials who voted for another party. Only the heads of the department and some of the ambassadors change, which often leads to rather odd choices - e.g., Rahm Emmanuel was recently appointed as the US ambassador to Japan - not only his expertise on Japan is questionable, but his reputation for F-language makes him a weird choice for the country, known for its sensitivity to politeness. On the other hand, [John Sullivan](https://www.politico.com/news/2022/02/20/john-sullivan-america-man-in-moscow-00010400) (Trump's appointment) was retained as the ambassador to Russia, due to his experience and knowledge of the country (Sullivan is a career diplomatic officer.)

**Tight money**
While Thatcher and Reagan are known for implementing contractionary monetary policies curbing the government spending, they were merely following the advice of economists, notably [Milton Friedman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monetary_policy) and Chicago school. At the time [Keynsian policies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keynesian_economics), introduced during the Great Depression, stopped working and persistent inflation ([stagflation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stagflation)) set in. While in the popular culture the [monetarists](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monetarism) are often associated with neoliberal politicians, whereas Keynsians are associated with more social policies, the Monetarism simply represented evolution of the economic thought in response to the inflation/stagflation, and was successful in curbing it. Although particular economists often subscribe to this or that of the [existing economic schools (Keynsians, Monetarists, New Keynsians, Austrian school, Marxists, etc.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schools_of_economic_thought), it is fair to say that actual economic policy is based on a synthesis of this knowledge.

---

Good and relatively accessible reading is:
[Modern Macroeconomics: Its Origins, Development and Current State](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1845422082) by Snowdon and Vane.

Comment: Carter has, in writing and in interviews, said that he was told by Volcker that he would move to tighten the money supply which would rein in inflation but probably cause a recession which would be politically disadvantageous to Carter. Carter chose to do what was best for the country and not for himself.

Comment: @DonHosek Business cycle is usually longer than one or two presidential terms, so any statements relating immediate economic developments to the actions of this or that politician/manager are rather suspect. For example, the current inflation is likely the consequence of the expansion of the money supply during the Obama administration... which is probably also true about the economic growth experienced during the Trump years (these are *the boom and the bust* in action).

Comment: I think the huge Covid stimulus (along with the combination of increased demand/tightened supply in that same time frame) is a more likely source of the current inflation than anything that happened before 2016.

Comment: @DonHosek Stimulus probably didn't improve the situation, but under Obama fed did triple (!) the money supply - this is a lot more than any stimulus in Obama, Trump or Biden era.

Comment: Where do you get that information from? This chart shows no such thing: http://www.shadowstats.com/alternate_data/money-supply-charts

Comment: @DonHosek I am talking here about the *monetary base*, the actual cash, M0. You can check, e.g., sections *Historical Chart by presidents (USD Million)* and *Money Supply M0 in United States by presidents* [under this link](https://take-profit.org/en/statistics/money-supply-m1/united-states/): it starts growing in the last year of Bush presidency and continues to grow throughout the Obama's term - the total increase is about sixfold.

Comment: @DonHosek [contd.] Your graph is M1-M3, which is essentially the loans by the commercial banks - it remained low because the conomy was in a *liquidity trap*. Once the economy recovered  and the banks began making loands again, but with increased monetary base, the inflation hit.

Answer (score 0):

[Federal Reserve System Nomination of Paul A. Volcker To Be Chairman of the Board of Governors.](https://web.archive.org/web/20171207173645/http://www.presidency.ucsb.edu/ws/?pid=32648), July 25, 1979

> [President Carter] said, in making the announcement, "Mr. Volcker has broad economic and financial experience and enjoys an outstanding international reputation. He shares my determination to vigorously pursue the battle against inflation at home and to ensure the strength and stability of the dollar abroad."

[Paul Volcker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paul_Volcker#Career) had served in several positions with the US government prior to his appointment as Fed Chair.

> - In 1952 Volcker joined the staff of the Federal Reserve Bank of New York as a full-time economist. He left that position in 1957 ...
> - In 1962, Robert Roosa, who had been his mentor at the Federal Reserve, hired him at the Treasury Department as director of financial analysis. In 1963, he became deputy under secretary for monetary affairs [leaving the post in 1965].
> - Appointed by the Nixon Administration, Volcker served as under secretary of the Treasury for international monetary affairs from 1969 to 1974.
> - In 1975, he became President of the Federal Reserve Bank of New York, and he retained that role until he became Federal Reserve Chair in August 1979.

When not working for the US government, Volcker worked in international banking with firms he would later be charged with regulating. His breadth of knowledge and practical experience made him well qualified to serve as Chairman of the Federal Reserve.

Comment: That's interesting, but surely there were other economists that the same could said about that were for more traditional policies?